# Conflict between defined assignment and intrinsic assignment (with nagfor)?

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, gfortran, intel-fortran, nag-fortran

Intrinsic polymorphic assignment is a recent feature of some Fortran compilers (e.g. ifort 18, nagfor 6.2) that is not available in older versions (e.g. ifort 17, gfortran 6.3). A well-known solution that works with these older versions is to use a defined assignment as in the example below (taken and adapted from the book of Chivers and Sleightholme):

```
module deftypes  
   type, abstract :: shape_t  
      integer :: x = 0, y = 0  
   end type shape_t  

   type, extends(shape_t) :: circle_t  
      integer :: radius = 0  
   end type circle_t  

   interface assignment(=)
      module procedure generic_shape_assign
   end interface   

contains  
   subroutine generic_shape_assign ( lhs, rhs )  
      class(shape_t),              intent(in ) :: rhs  
      class(shape_t), allocatable, intent(out) :: lhs  
      print*,' --> in generic_shape_assign'  
      allocate(lhs, source = rhs)  
   end subroutine generic_shape_assign
end module deftypes  

program check_assign  
   use deftypes  
   implicit none  
   class(shape_t), allocatable :: myshape
   type (circle_t)             :: mycirc1, mycirc2  

   mycirc1 = circle_t ( 1, 2, 3 )    

   print*,'A polymorphic assignment: myshape = mycirc1'  
   myshape = mycirc1  

   print*,'An intrinsic assignment: mycirc2 = mycirc1'   
   mycirc2 = mycirc1
end program check_assign
```

This example, compiles and works well with ifort 15.0.3 and gfortran 6.3.0. But with nagfor 6.2 I get the following error during the compilation (for the line `mycirc2=mycirc1`):

```
Error: check_assign.f90, line 41: Incorrect data type CIRCLE_T (expected SHAPE_T) for argument LHS (no. 1) of GENERIC_SHAPE_ASSIGN
```

It's not clear to me why this compiler is trying to use the defined assignment in the instruction `mycirc2 = mycirc1` while these two variables are not allocatable polymorphic ones.

Of course, if I delete the defined assignment it works with nagfor but not with the other old compilers. Any idea where this error came from and how to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the compiler is correct to reject this program.  However, if you have a support contract with NAG I strongly advise asking them over taking my comments as definitive.

I will show my reasoning.

It is clear that the reference to the specific procedure `generic_shape_assign` like

```
type(circle_t) mycirc1, mycirc2
call generic_shape_assign(mycirc2, mycirc1)
```

is not valid.  It fails because the actual argument `mycirc2`, corresponding to the allocatable polymorphic dummy argument `lhs`:

- is not allocatable;
- is not of the same *declared* type as the corresponding dummy argument;
- is not polymorphic.

The error message you quote covers rejection of the program for violating this second.

So, that means that `generic_shape_assign` is not a valid specific procedure (for this reference) with generic specification `assignment(=)`, right?  And thus no defined assignment is chosen and the compiler should fall back to intrinsic assignment?

This is where things get murky (at least to me).

I think that the specific subroutine `generic_shape_assign` *is* chosen for the defined assignment and the compiler is therefore correct to reject your program because you aren't calling this specific subroutine correctly.

Let's look further, using Fortran 2008 7.2.1.4 where there's definition of when an assignment statement is a defined assignment statement.

To decide whether the subroutine `generic_shape_assign` defines the defined assignment statement `mycirc2=mycirc1` we look at the given points:

1. `generic_shape_assign` is a subroutine with two dummy arguments (`lhs` and `rhs` here);
2. the interface block gives `generic_shape_assign` the generic spec `assignment(=)`;
3. `lhs` (of type `shape_t`) is type compatible with `mycirc2` (of dynamic type `circle_t`); `rhs` similarly;
4. there are no type parameters for dummy or actual arguments;
5. the ranks (being scalar) of the dummy and actual arguments match.

We meet all of the requirements for this being a defined assignment: there is no requirement which states that defined assignment requires the chosen subroutine to be callable!

In summary:

> It's not clear to me why this compiler is trying to use the defined assignment in the instruction `mycirc2 = mycirc1` while these two variables are not allocatable polymorphic ones.

Because whether defined assignment is used is unrelated to whether the left- and right-hand sides are polymorphic or allocatable.

Finally, I think the diagnostic message from the compiler could be improved whether my reasoning is correct or incorrect.

Comment: "And thus no defined assignment is chosen and the compiler should fall back to intrinsic assignment?" Yes that's what I think. I just checked with the recent compilers ifort 18 and gfortran 8.1 (even if the defined assignment is here superfluous since polymorphic assignment is allowed with these compilers as with nag one) and I don't get any error messages and the results are correct.  Yes, I will ask the nag support in the next few days as soon as I have purchased this compiler (I only used the trial version) and I will report their answer here.Thanks francescalus.

Comment: I would be very interested to hear an answer from a compiler developer.  Experts also gather on the comp.lang.fortran newsgroup.

Comment: And I should add, _if_ I'm correct and the program is invalid, it isn't invalid in such a way as the compiler is required to detect/diagnose.

Comment: Sorry for this very long period of time. As promised I asked the Nag's support and they completely confirm your analysis. They "agree that the compiler message could be improved and believe that the wording in the Standard will be improved to better guide compiler writers  and users." Thank you again francescalus for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It's good to know that this answer isn't wrong.